# Combining Pandas Subplots into a Single Figure

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I'm having trouble understanding Pandas subplots - and how to create axes so that all subplots are shown (not over-written by subsequent plot).

For each "Site", I want to make a time-series plot of all columns in the dataframe.

The "Sites" here are 'shark' and 'unicorn', both with 2 variables. The output should be be 4 plotted lines - the time-indexed plot for Var 1 and Var2 at each site.

[image]

**Make Time-Indexed Data with Nans:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 

    # some ways to create random data
    'Var1':pd.np.random.randn(100),
    'Var2':pd.np.random.randn(100),
    'Site':pd.np.random.choice( ['unicorn','shark'], 100),

    # a date range and set of random dates
    'Date':pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=100, freq='D'),
#     'f':pd.np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=365, 
#                           freq='D'), 100, replace=False) 
    })
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df['Var2']=df.Var2.cumsum()
df.loc['2011-01-31' :'2011-04-01', 'Var1']=pd.np.nan
```

**Make a figure with a sub-plot for each site:**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(df.Site.unique()), 1)
counter=0
for site in df.Site.unique():
    print(site)
    sitedat=df[df.Site==site]
    sitedat.plot(subplots=True, ax=ax[counter], sharex=True)
    ax[0].title=site #Set title of the plot to the name of the site
    counter=counter+1
plt.show()
```

However, this is not working as written. The second sub-plot ends up overwriting the first. In my actual use case, I have 14 variable number of sites in each dataframe, as well as a variable number of 'Var1, 2, ...'. Thus, I need a solution that does not require creating each axis (ax0, ax1, ...) by hand.

As a bonus, I would love a title of each 'site' above that set of plots.

The current code over-writes the first 'Site' plot with the second. What I missing with the axes here?!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using [`DataFrame.plot(..., subplot=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) you need to provide the correct number of axes that will be used for each column (and with the right geometry, if using `layout=`). In your example, you have 2 columns, so `plot()` needs two axes, but you are only passing one in `ax=`, therefore pandas has no choice but to delete all the axes and create the appropriate number of axes itself.

Therefore, you need to pass an array of axes of length corresponding to the number of columns you have in your dataframe.

```
# the grouper function is from itertools' cookbook
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(df.Site.unique())*(len(df.columns)-1),1, sharex=True)
for (site,sitedat),axList in zip(df.groupby('Site'),grouper(axs,len(df.columns)-1)):
    sitedat.plot(subplots=True, ax=axList)
    axList[0].set_title(site)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]